# Edit specific input button based on user input, and save it with a separate button in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an input, it has its value from the beginning.
Then, when the user double click on a span, the cursor needs to be in input field and the user should be able to edit it.
Once edit is ready, he needs to press save button in order to save it, not just click outside of the input field(which is by default)

The second button will just delete, reset the name string, and then once again when you press save, it will save the empty string.

All that, will depend on which span the user is dblckicking, so the respective input of a respective span has to be accessed for edit.

I've done something like this for now..
But it's far to be ready. Would appreciate you're ideas.
I need to do it using vanilla JavaScript

```js
var numberOfbuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".name").length;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfbuttons; ++i) {
     
      document.querySelectorAll('.name')[i].ondblclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('in1').disabled = false;    
      document.getElementById('in1').value = 'hahmmm';
      };
      
}
```

```html
<span id="spn1" class="name">
   <input id="in1" type="text" disabled="true" value="Homer Simpson">
   <div class="namefunc">
      <button class="check">save</button>
      <button class="close">delete</button>
   </div>
</span>
<span id="spn2" class="name">
   <input id="in2" type="text" disabled="true" value="Marge Simpson">
   <div class="namefunc">
      <button class="check">save</button>
      <button class="close">delete</button>
   </div>
</span>
<span id="spn3" class="name">
   <input id="in3" type="text" disabled="true" value="Bart Simpson">
   <div class="namefunc">
      <button class="check">save</button>
      <button class="close">delete</button>
   </div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the correct input field editable, you must not work with the ID of the first input field in the loop. Here is a way to select the correct input field via the double-clicked span element:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".name").forEach(span => {
    span.ondblclick = function() {
        let input = span.querySelector("input");
        input.disabled = false;
        input.value = "hahmmm";
        input.focus();
        span.querySelector("button.check").onclick = function() {
            input.disabled = true;
        }
        span.querySelector("button.close").onclick = function() {
            if (input.disabled == false) {
                input.value = "";
                input.focus();
            }
        }
    }
});

window.onclick = function() {
    let active_input = document.querySelector("input:not([disabled])");
    if (active_input) {
        active_input.focus();
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the save button is supposed to do. Right now it just disables the input field again, keeping the new value.

Comment: wow! that's exactly what I need, except how to exit focus only when pressing save? since right now it exits focus when you press outside of the input field too.

Comment: @Vladimir: Ah, I see. I don't know if that can be prevented. But you can at least re-bind focus to the active input field with each click in the window. (I added the code for this above.)